# What are the proper dimensions for a background image in an android app?

Tags: android

I would like to create a background image for my app in Photoshop. I understand that I will need to create three different files at the appropriate dpi for ldpi, mdpi and hdpi. But what are the appropriate dimensions and resolutions for each?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dimension varies by phone. Android will scale them slightly. Check out [Android Developer's site](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Comment: I probably reference that site more than any other for Android dev.